# How do I create a Gnutls-Client which sends its certificate to the server?

Tags: c++, c, ssl

I'm trying to code an Gnutls-client in C++.
Unfortunatly there isn't much Documentation or Examples.
I setup a Session like this:

```
gnutls_certificate_allocate_credentials (&x509_cred);
gnutls_certificate_set_x509_key_file (x509_cred, certfile.c_str(), keyfile.c_str(),GNUTLS_X509_FMT_PEM);
gnutls_certificate_set_verify_function (x509_cred, _verify_certificate_callback);
gnutls_credentials_set (session, GNUTLS_CRD_CERTIFICATE, x509_cred);
```

But my server receives no certificate. 
It works if I use the gnutls-cli programm, so I think it should be something in the code above.

What do I wrong?

Hope for awnser,

Spartacus

Comment: Looking here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gnutls/manual/gnutls.pdf in chapter 8 you find some examples.

Comment: Maybe the same problem like here? http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.gnutls.general/145

Answer (score 2):

Following the hints of the discussion I cited above[1] I could get a GnuTLS client sending the certificate:

The server has to ask for the certificate, otherwise the client won't send anything.

`gnutls_certificate_server_set_request (mSession, GNUTLS_CERT_REQUEST);`

The client automatically sends only certificates which match the CA's the server trusts in.

If you want to override this, you must install a callback on certificate requests on the client side:

`gnutls_certificate_client_set_retrieve_function (credentials, cert_callback);`

Inside the callback you can choose the certificate/key to send:

```
static int cert_callback (gnutls_session_t session,
      const gnutls_datum_t * req_ca_rdn,
      int nreqs,
      const gnutls_pk_algorithm_t * sign_algos, int sign_algos_length,
       gnutls_retr_st * st) {
       // Check CA's requested by server
       // Check Algorithms accepted by server

       // Putting in our key / cert, even if not trusted by the sever
       st->cert.x509   = &myCert;
       st->ncerts = 1;
       st->key.x509    = myKey;
       st->deinit_all = 0;
       return 0; // no error
}
```

For more a complete source of cert_callback look at cli.c from gnutls-cli.

Source:
[1] http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.gnutls.general/145